# Powershell, best way to verify current directory equals something

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am new to powershell.

I have the following problem: I am trying to check if current directory equals expected directory stored on a variable.

Someting like:

```
Set-Variable tsDir  -Value "mydir\subdir"
if(!((Test-Path [$tsDir]) -and (($pwd).path -eq $tsDir)))
{
     Write-Host "Wrong dir"
     exit
}
Keep-Going ...
```

However it don't work, even as printing $pwd and $tsDir looks equal. Do I need something special? Maybe is returning an object and I neet to cast to a string? How I do it?

I also want to make it case-insensitive (windows).

Thanks for any tip you can gave me :)

Comment: `$pwd` contains the full path. You appear to be searching a partial path. You can try `$pwd.path.Contains($tsDir)`.

Comment: Thank you, you put me on the right track. I ended up doing: if(!((Test-Path $tsDir) -and ($pwd.Path.ToLower().Equals($tsDir.ToLower()))))